# Convert matlab method to python

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, tensorflow

There is very helpful method in matlab called "getwb()".
For developers that coding neural network, this method returns the weights and biases at the final iteration. 
I have neural network (using tensorflow tools).
There is possible to convert this method in some way?

I tried alot with tensorFlow.saver() and restore() but I don`t really understand this issue.

thanks!

**EDIT:**
my model is:

```
def neuralNetworkModel(x):
  # first step: (input * weights) + bias, linear operation like y = ax + b
  # each layer connection to other layer will represent by nodes(i) * nodes(i+1)

  for i in range(0,numberOfLayers):
    if i == 0:
      hiddenLayers.append({"weights": tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([sizeOfRow, nodesLayer[i]])),
                      "biases": tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([nodesLayer[i]]))})

    elif i > 0 and i < numberOfLayers-1:
      hiddenLayers.append({"weights" : tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([nodesLayer[i], nodesLayer[i+1]])),
                  "biases" : tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([nodesLayer[i+1]]))})
    else:
      outputLayer = {"weights": tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([nodesLayer[i], classes])),
                  "biases": tensorFlow.Variable(tensorFlow.random_normal([classes]))}


  # create the layers
  for i in range(numberOfLayers):
    if i == 0:
      layers.append(tensorFlow.add(tensorFlow.matmul(x, hiddenLayers[i]["weights"]), hiddenLayers[i]["biases"]))
      layers.append(tensorFlow.nn.relu(layers[i]))  # pass values to activation function (i.e sigmoid, softmax) and add it to the layer

    elif i >0 and i < numberOfLayers-1:
      layers.append(tensorFlow.add(tensorFlow.matmul(layers[i-1], hiddenLayers[i]["weights"]), hiddenLayers[i]["biases"]))
      layers.append(tensorFlow.nn.relu(layers[i]))

  output = tensorFlow.matmul(layers[numberOfLayers-1], outputLayer["weights"]) + outputLayer["biases"]
  finalOutput = output
  return output
```

Comment: Consider adding some details and code: what model do you train? how do you do it? what did you try and how it did not work?

Comment: thanks, I`ve updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create a bunch of variables for weights and biases of hidden and output layers. You should be able to retrieve them at any moment (when a session is active) by using tf.Session.run() like follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

v = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((5, 5)))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  v_val = sess.run(v)  
  print v_val
```

I also advise to use tf.learn library that contains useful abstractions like [fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/contrib.layers.html#fully_connected) layer.